# Performance Tuning - Number of database calls

Tags: java, database, jdbc

In our codebase, we have several database queries which we think are not optimized. But before starting optimizations we want to analyse how many calls our code base (java) performing in specific set of operation.

Is there any way or tool, which can provide me that information. For example, 
we have page1 which when we hit, query the database. Statements are written like `select * from ( select * from (select * from..........`

We need the count only.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

I really like the integrated profiler in Netbeans. If you turn on methods-profiling, you get a estimated rough amount of how many calls are made and how long they took. Take a look here for a guide how to use it: [link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-intro.html)

Answer (score -1):

Can you please help me to understand which type of java application are you running are you using spring? and which orm (hibernate , mybatis or spring jdbc) are you using?

For now you can try below options and monitor the logs

Hibernate:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

MyBatis

log4j.logger.yourmapperpackage=DEBUG
```

Spring JDBC:

```
<category name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <priority value="debug" />
</category>
```